# How to find Distinct Field with two column using Aggegation MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have category code and category name with group and other field group with array.
sample data-

```
[
   {
      "categoryCode":"categoryCode1",
      "categoryName":"categoryName1",
      "cat_type":A
   },
   {
      "categoryCode":"categoryCode1",
      "categoryName":"categoryName1",
      "cat_type":B
   },
   {
      "categoryCode":"categoryCode2",
      "categoryName":"categoryName2",
      "cat_type":B
   }
]
```

and expected output:

```
[
   {
      "categoryCode":"categoryCode1",
      "categoryName":"categoryName1",
      "cat_type":[A,B]
   },
   {
      "categoryCode":"categoryCode2",
      "categoryName":"categoryName2",
      "cat_type":[B]
   }
]
```

how can acheive this with distinct value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `$group` aggregation stage with `$addToSet` operator for the respective field.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": {
        "categoryCode": "$categoryCode",
        "categoryName": "$categoryName",
        
      },
      "cat_type": {
        "$addToSet": "$cat_type"
      }
    },
    
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "_id": 0,
      "categoryCode": "$_id.categoryCode",
      "categoryName": "$_id.categoryName",
      "cat_type": "$cat_type"
    }
  },
  
])
```

[Mongo Playground Sample Execution](https://mongoplayground.net/p/4JXMa0I9ymM)